# PHP - Convert octal/hexadecimal escape sequences

Tags: php, string, ascii, octal

I'm not sure about the exact naming of this php functionality so if you have advice for a better title to this question is welcome.

The point is, I have some string written in this way `"ge\164\x42as\145\x44\151\x72"` and I would like to convert them in readable chars ( for example the above string value is `"getBaseDir"`)

How can I accomplish this in a programmatically way using php ?

**Update**
Those strings are contained in a php source file that I would like to parse and clean in order to be more readable.

So I would appreciate a solution that provide me a way to parse and covert this string all at once ( for example with a regex ) ...

here a portion of the code so it is more easy to understand the scenario

```
 public function cmp($x74, $x7a)
    {
        $x76 = $this->x1c->x3380->{$this->xc1->x3380->xe269};
        $x12213 = "\x68\145\x6c\x70\x65\x72";
        $x11f45 = "\x67\x65\164\123t\x6fr\x65Co\156\146\x69\147";

        if ($x76(${$this->x83->x3380->{$this->x83->x3380->{$this->x83->x3380->xd341}}}) == $x76(${$this->x83->x336e->{$this->xc1->x336e->{$this->xc1->x336e->x8445}}})) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($x76(${$this->x83->x334c->{$this->x83->x334c->x3423}}) < $x76(${$this->x83->x336e->{$this->xc1->x336e->{$this->xc1->x336e->x8445}}})) ? 1 : -1;
    }
```

Just to clear the above code is part of an extension that we legitimate purchase but we need to customize.

Comment: Is that string literally written like that in *PHP source code*, or are you getting that as a value from elsewhere? If it's already in source code, you merely need to output it: `echo "ge\164\x42as\145\x44\151\x72";`

Comment: The string above contains a mix of octal escape sequences (e.g. \164) and hexademical escape sequences (e.g. \x42). PHP can deal with both of these natively. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.

Comment: @deceze yes it is in the code ( actually it is a stupid way some devs has `scrumbled` their code, I hate this kind of things )
I will test your suggestion  ... if you can put it in a answer I will accept it once I'm sure it is working for me

Comment: So `echo "ge\164\x42as\145\x44\151\x72";` works...!?

Comment: it works but I need a return value

Comment: "***Just to clear the above code is part of an extension that we legitimate purchase but we need to customize.***" Why don't you contact the developer?

Comment: Because they probably want extra money for this kind of service and can do the customization by myself

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = '"\125n\141\x62\154\145\40to\x67\145\156e\x72\141t\145\x20\x74\x68e\40d\x61t\141\40\146\145\145d\x2e"';

\\ convert the octal into string
$string = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\([0-7]{1,3})/', function ($m) {
    return chr(octdec($m[1]));
}, $string);

\\ convert the hexadecimal part of the string
$string = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\x([0-9A-F]{1,2})/i', function ($m) {
    return chr(hexdec($m[1]));
}, $string);
```

on this particular situation I need to parse a full file content match all string delimited by `""` and convert them, here the full solution

```
$content = file_get_contents($filepath);

// match all string delimited by ""
$content = preg_replace_callback("/(\".*?\")/s ", function ($m) {
    $string = $m[1];

    \\ convert the octal into string
    $string = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\([0-7]{1,3})/', function ($m) {
        return chr(octdec($m[1]));
    }, $string);

    \\ convert the hexadecimal part of the string
    $string = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\x([0-9A-F]{1,2})/i', function ($m) {
        return chr(hexdec($m[1]));
    }, $string);

    return $string;

}, $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I accomplish this in a programmatically way using php ?

You can simply echo it:

```
echo "ge\164\x42as\145\x44\151\x72";
//getBaseDir
```

Comment: You can comment the preg_replace line out and this runs exactly the same. It also uses the /e preg_replace modifier which has been deprecated for years.

Comment: `Warning: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Deprecated functionality: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead`
do you think I can use this regex to parse all php code at once ?

Comment: actually `echo` is not sufficient because I need a return value

Comment: @WonderLand the answer as been updated, while you were commenting, tks anyway.

Comment: Can you please clarify "***return value***" ?

Comment: @WonderLand You'll have to clarify the circumstances under which you get those strings. Again, merely the fact of writing this string as a PHP source code literal "deobfuscates" it. From there you can assign it to a variable or output it or do whatever you want. If that is not your starting condition, **clarify** your situation and desired outcome.

Comment: If you need a return value (I guess you want to use it in a function), use `print()`. PS : doubles quotes around your string is important. e.g `function fx($str) {return print($str);};`

Comment: I have updated the question, I hope it is more clear ... sorry for the confusion an thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$ret = print_r("\\012", true);
```

Comment: Could you please format your code by highlighting it and hitting Ctrl+K

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php
$inputString = "ge\164\x42as\145\x44\151\x72";

// Replace escape sequences with their corresponding characters
$properFormatString = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\([0-7]{1,3})/', function ($matches) {
    return chr(octdec($matches[1]));
}, $inputString);

echo $properFormatString;
?>
```